# Find nature of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Find nature of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{\cos{\frac{πn}{2}}}{n}}$$

It should be convergent, but I don’t know how to get to this result. It’s an exercise in a calculus 1 testbook.

**I’d like a full answer which explains which test or theorem we use to prove the series rigorously, not a one-sentence-answer, because I need to understand how to prove it, and if I’m missing something that I could use to prove other series.**

**METHOD 1: FAILED**

I have tried using the absolute convergence test, since it is not a series with non negative terms, and then using the ratio test, the root test, the comparison test or using asymptotic equivalences, but I wasn’t able to get to a conclusion.

**METHOD 2: DOES THIS LEAD ANYWHERE?**

I also tried re-writing the nth partial sums of the series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left\vert \frac{\cos{\frac{πn}{2}}}{n}\right\vert} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { \frac{\left\vert\cos{\frac{πn}{2}}\right\vert}{n}} $$ and, by ignoring all the terms for which $\cos{\frac{πn}{2}} = 0$, I got:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m} {\frac{\left\vert\cos{\frac{πn}{2}}\right\vert}{n}} = \frac{0}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{0}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + … + \frac{\left\vert\cos{\frac{πn}{2}}\right\vert}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\frac{m}{2}} {\frac{1}{2n}}$$

if m is even, otherwise (if m is odd) just substitute $\frac{m-1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{m}{2}$ on the upper bound of the summation.

But even this doesn’t get me anywhere, since I don’t know how to say if the sequence of the nth partial sums of the series has a supremum.

**NOTE**

By calculating the limits of the ratio test and the root test i got, respectively, a non existing limit and l=1, for which the root test doesn’t give useful answers.

Comment: This series is convergent: $\cos\frac{\pi n}{2}$ is either $-1$ or $1$ (value $0$ doesn't interest us), and $\frac{1}{n}$ is a nonnegative sequence that tends monotonically to $0$. There are some gaps to fill in (regarding value $0$ of cosine). Edit: name of this test is Leibniz Criterion.

Comment: This series is simply $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k}.$

Comment: @mowzorn I don’t get how this is enough though. $\frac{1}{n}$ is a monotonically decreasing function that tends to zero, but $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} {\frac{1}{n}}$ is divergent

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: note, that for $n=2$ we have $\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi \cdot 2}{2})}{n}$= $-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, if you want to put as an answer why my series is identical to the one you suggested, i’ll mark it as the answer to my question

Comment: @mowzorn I now understood your comment, but my problem was in rewriting the nth partial sum of the series to then apply the Leibniz Criterion, not the with the criterion itself.

Comment: @mathguruu no, see the absolut value.

Comment: @JacopoSenoner but your original series has not the absolute value). therefore if you will write the first 5 terms, you will see, that your original series is written by Anne Bauval in the second comment